# how to store an array from a multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, haml

i am currently using this select `= select(:schedule, :selected_players, @players.map { |p| [full_name(p), p.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None'}, "data-placeholder" => 'Add Players to Lineup', :prompt => 'Add Players to Lineup', :multiple => "multiple")`

and would like to store the information into an array within the database, then access this array for different pars of the site

there is a copy of things im needing to know

1. how best to store into the database, current this field value is binary
2. how to then extract each value from the array

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`serialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize).

If you make the `selected_players` column a text column and mark your `Schedule` model with

```
serialize :selected_players
```

Then you can save a Ruby array into the attribute. It'll be written to the database in YAML, and pop out exactly as it went in, as an array, when you read it.

Comment: that worked a treat, though how can i reference these values which are ids against another table for example to get the members name?