# Rails: Display Selected Value in Multi Select Form Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a multi select field, and I can see that I'm saving the array of values to the database, but when I return to the form, the values don't display as selected in the actual form field.

In this example, "ringmetaltype" is my field in the "items" table. For what it's worth, I've also updated item_params in the items controller to include ":ringmetaltype=>[]"

```
<%= form.select :ringmetaltype, options_for_select(["10K White Gold", "14K White Gold", "18K White Gold"],:selected => @item.ringmetaltype),{},{:multiple => true, :class => "form-control"} %>
```

Comment: change `:ringmetaltype` to `:ringmetaltypes`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Ran a migration, changed the name of the column to include the "s", still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after hours of searching. I needed to add

```
serialize :ringmetaltype
```

to my Model. Found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11934886/5101088